# console.log() statements do not appear in Safari error log

Tags: javascript, safari, debugging, webkit

I am debugging a Safari-specific javascript issue, and I can't get `console.log` to output to the error log. This is a [documented feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Console/Console.html) of Safari (I'm using version 4.0.3). These statements in my code just seem to be ignored, however. Why?

Comment: You have any example code? need to open the console first to see errors? Any other relevant information? It's very hard to troubleshoot a "X doesn't work. Why?" sort of question.

Comment: You could for instance build a page with a script that has nothing but a console.log statement, and work on that. This will ferret out any issues that may lay elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You could also try typing it straight into the console to see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Breton and SeanJA for their suggestions of testing directly in the console and making an example file. After doing this, I realized that console.log was, in fact, working in an isolated environment. This made me realize that it must be something particular to my development environment. Checking around, I found that there was some JavaScript being loaded early on, designed to define the console object for non-Firebug-enabled browsers.

```
if (!("console" in window) || !("firebug" in console))
 {
     var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
     "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];

     window.console = {};
     for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
         window.console[names[i]] = function() {}
 }
```

This was apparently written before Safari had implemented a console object for its error window.

I've removed that and now everything works well. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the mac or windows build?

On the windows build I can't use most of the stuff in the "Develop" men, none of the javascript options work for me. I can only use

- Open page with
- User Agent
- Show snipper editor
- Disable *